# Starting and stopping X11 and LXDE from command line

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with Debian Wheezy (Raspbian) and so far I've managed to learn quite a lot about Linux just playing around, but I have a few questions for all you seasoned Linux pros out there.

1) From command line, if I execute `startx`, X11 will launch followed by LXDE. If I had a monitor connected, I'm imagining I would see a transition from command line to the desktop environment. Can I launch X11 first with `x`, then start LXDE on top of X11 afterwards with `/etc/init.d/lxdm start` (is this correct?) and get to the same result as `startx`?

2) Instead, let's say I executed `/etc/init.d/lxdm start` alone, would X11 start automatically (since LXDE relies on X11)?

3) From desktop, if I `CTRL+ALT+F1` to get back to command line, then I should be able to shutdown LXDE using `/etc/init.d/lxdm stop`. Does X11 automatically close with the termination of LXDE?

4) What is the proper/safe way to shutdown X11?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) If you launch X by itself, you'll likely find yourself sitting there with a blank grey screen with an X for the mouse cursor. The X window system provides the ability to put graphics onto the screen, but you need other components to actually put the things onto the screen. Starting LXDM starts X as it is a dependency for LXDM to actually run, so there is no real reason to start X first and then use `/etc/init.d/lxdm start`.

2) Yes it would. You're starting the Desktop Manager which then starts the desktop environment to provide you with a GUI.

3) Yes it does. The Desktop Manager (LXDM) is what provides X in the form of the LXDE (Desktop Environment)

4) I use `/etc/init.d/lxdm stop`.
Generally using the `init.d` scripts are the safest way to stop services to ensure that no stale files are left behind. With X though, I don't think there is any harm is just doing a `killall -9 lxdm`

Comment: Just installed lxde on Debian 9.5 - but I have no /etc/init.d/lxdm on my system...

Comment: Did you install LXDM too? I believe the default DM on Debian is LightDM

Comment: Oh... no I didn't install LXDM. Wouldn't I have gotten that when I installed LXDE? And do I really need to install something separately just to stop LXDE??

Comment: LXDE doesn't always install LXDM. If you have lightdm installed, you just run `/etc/init.d/lightdm stop` instead of `lxdm`

Comment: I don't have `lxdm` installed. But do I really need that to LXDE?! I don't quite understand LXDE vs LXDM...

Comment: @TheStoryCoder https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20385/windows-managers-vs-login-managers-vs-display-managers-vs-desktop-environment <== this answer might help you there.